# replace() method doesn't remove white space and while loop doesn't continue

Tags: python

Basically I used `.replace()` in order to remove whitespace in the beginning or the end in case the user writes "yes" with spaces. I have tried using `strip()` but nothing happens either. I'm assuming that the method isn't working because when I type an answer with spacing in the input, it outputs "Invalid answer, try again!" whereas I would like it to output the random number.
Also, after I write an invalid answer and it asks me if I would like to roll the the dice and I say yes, nothing happens. I thought that it would give me a number because of the while loop, since the answer is yes.

So here is my code:

```
from random import randrange


answer = (input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")).capitalize().strip()


while answer == "Yes" or answer =="Y" :
  random_number = randrange(1, 7)
  print("You got number %i!" % random_number)
  answer = (input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")).capitalize().strip()

if answer == "No" or answer =="n":
  print("Maybe next time!")
else :
  print("Invalid answer, try again!")
  answer = (input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")).capitalize()
```

Edit: I noticed that it removes whitespace only in the end and not in the beginning.

Comment: Your indentations need to be fixed.

Comment: Use `strip()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

|      String.strip([chars])
 |
 |      Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing
 |      whitespace removed.
 |      If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
i.e.

```
>>> a=" yes "
>>> a.strip()
'yes'
```

Based on your comment I suspect that your code is failing by capitalising the initial space in the answer.
Try combining the strip and capitalize

i.e.

```
>>> a = " yes "
>>> a.strip().capitalize()
'Yes'
```

I suspect that this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
from random import randrange

while True:
    answer = (input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")).strip().capitalize()
    if answer == "Yes" or answer =="Y" :
        random_number = randrange(1, 7)
        print("You got number %i!" % random_number)

    elif answer == "No" or answer =="N":
        print("Maybe next time!")
        break
    else :
        print("Invalid answer, try again!")
```

Comment: @lepi See my answer to your comment

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a newline character at the end of thr string and it isn't a space and it survives through your `.replace`.

Use `.rstrip("\n")` to get rid of it, or better yet, just drop the `.replace` and use `.strip()` directly to get rid of surrounding whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove whitespace on the beginning and end is to use .strip()

```
    answer = (input("Would you like to roll the dice? \n")).capitalize()
    answer = answer.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have some bugs in your code:

1. inside the while loop you forgot to do the replace.
2. In case of Invalid answer you are out of the loop the the code would fail.

the other answers are not relevant, although using strip is better practice
in this case.

also, do not worry about the newline [ibug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) mention, input is already tacking care of it :
[image]

Comment: I know I didn't use do the replace inside the while loop but I have tried and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @lepi can you update your question with your current code?